# Modify Firefox titlebar through Javascript Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, titlebar

I have an extension for Firefox written in Javascript that I would like to make able to append text to the window's titlebar. Is this possible?

Comment: It must be possible, as the Firesomething extension does it: http://www.cosmicat.com/extensions/firesomething/  (Probably my favourite Firefox extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the document.title property to dynamically change your page's title, which is what it shows in the window's titlebar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.title += "The Text You Want To Add";
</script>
```

Comment: Will this change when the user navigates to another page? Is there a way to make it permanent.

Comment: Not sure on that one. I'd assume not, you'd have to run the document.title on every page load. Can't say for sure though.

Comment: Yes, you would have to set this on every page seperately.